# FIFO inventory systems - Converting T-SQL to Linq

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql

Please how do I convert this T-SQL statement to Linq or lambda? Trying to implement FIFO inventory systems

```
DECLARE @TakenQty int;
SET @TakenQty = 90;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY accept_date, id ASC) AS CumQty 
    FROM RS_GIN_Master 
    WHERE qty > 0
)
SELECT TOP ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE CumQty <@TakenQty)+1) 
    batch_no, accept_date,
    CASE
       WHEN CumQty < @TakenQty THEN qty
       ELSE @TakenQty - (CumQty - Qty)
    END AS TakenOut
FROM
    cte
```

Table definition

[image]

The final result is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<History>()
            {
                new History(1,1,20,DateTime.Now.AddDays(-24),"001"),
                new History(2,1,2,DateTime.Now.AddDays(-23),"002"),
                new History(3,2,2,DateTime.Now.AddDays(-24),"001"),
                new History(3,1,29,DateTime.Now.AddDays(-22),"003"),
                new History(3,1,50,DateTime.Now.AddDays(-21),"004"),
            };

    var demo = Results(data, 30);

    demo.Dump(); //note using LinqPad
}

public class History
{
    public History(int id, int stockId, int qty, DateTime date, string batchNumber)
    {
        Id = id;
        StockId = stockId;
        Qty = qty;
        Date = date;
        BatchNumber = batchNumber;
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public static List<Result> Results(List<History> data, int takenQty)
{
    var runningTotal = 0;

    var result = data.Where(p => p.StockId == 1).OrderBy(p => p.Date).ThenBy(p => p.Id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.Date,
            x.BatchNumber,
            x.Qty,
            x.StockId,
            CumQty = (runningTotal = runningTotal + x.Qty)
        }).ToList();


    var query = result.Select(x => new Result
    {
    StockId =x.StockId,
        Id = x.Id,
        BatchNumber = x.BatchNumber,
        Qty = x.Qty,
        Used = x.CumQty < takenQty ? x.Qty : takenQty - (x.CumQty - x.Qty)
    }).Take((result.Count(p => p.CumQty < takenQty)) + 1).ToList();

    return query;
}

public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    public int Used { get; set; }
    public int Left => Qty - Used;
}
```

And the final output 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Please how do I convert this T-SQL statement to Linq or lambda?

You don't.

LINQ and SQL share many common query operators, but LINQ has nothing equivalent to

```
SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY accept_date, id ASC) RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

Which is what that expression is shorthand for.  And it certainly has no way to write an expression that EF could *translate* to this TSQL.

So you leave it in TSQL.  And if you must have an implementation outside of SQL Server, you start from scratch.